# Given a complexity class C for problems which can be solved using exponential time and an exponential number of random bits. C ⊆ NEXP?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, randomized-algorithms, nondeterminism, randomness

There must be a complexity class C that includes exactly the problems that can be solved in exponential time and having access to a truly random coin (which in turns implies that you will be able to use an exponential number of random bits). I searched for a class like like this in the Complexity Zoo but I only found PEXP, which seems to be the exponential version of PP, and I think I am looking for the exponential version of ZPP.

Is C ⊆ NEXP. Since ZPP ⊆ RP ⊆ NP, it would seem likely that C ⊆ NEXP. Furthermore, based only on intuition, I think a non deterministic machine would be able to branch in every point in which the algorithm for C would have tossed a coin: one branch would continue with the algorithm assuming the outcome was "tails" and the other branch would assume the outcome was "heads". Am I wrong in thinking that these random bits can be simulated by non determinism?

Comment: Good question! I'm also curious about why there seems to be no much research around ZPEXP (maybe it's explored before?), so I searched on google and found [this](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sarah/tr-02.ps). Maybe it can bring you more ideas.

Comment: Interesting, I will definitely give that a read. At least now I know its name (it makes perfect sense that it is called ZPEXP, I should have tried to google that before). Thanks!

Comment: About names of these class there are such entries in Complexity Zoo: ZPTIME, BPTIME (but no RTIME, I don't know why) for generalized ZPP and BPP and so on. In fact ZPP are defined as ZPTIME(poly(n)) (similar for BPP and ZPEXP).

Comment: Using that name ZPTIME, I managed to find a [document](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse531/16wi/lectures/lect11.pdf) in which it is stated that ZPTIME(f(n)) ⊆ RPTIME(f(n)), (Theorem 1.5, although there it is stated as _ZPTIME(T(n)) = RTIME(T(n)) ∩ coRTIME(T(n))_, but it is possible to infer the inclusion from that) and it is also stated that RPTIME(f(n)) ⊆ NTIME(f(n)) (at the end of Definition 1.3). From those two statements, we can show that ZPTIME(f(n)) ⊆ NTIME(f(n)), which corresponds with my hypothesis that ZPEXP ⊆ NEXP. I will have to review this "proof" later. Thanks again!